# creating a datagridview form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I`m new to c# and windows form applications.
Right now, I want to create a Datagridview within my form, whose rows I want to fill with the properties of a business object. I followed the example from this msdn page: [How to: Bind Objects to Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0wfd4yz.aspx) and created my own program, but instead of getting a similar result as in the msdn example I get a datagridview with three empty rows. What am I doing wrong? Here is my program:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;


public class Form3 : Form
{
    private DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
    private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

    public Form3()
    {            
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(EnumsAndComboBox_Load);
    }

    private void EnumsAndComboBox_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Populate the data source.           
        bindingSource1.Add(new Test("bli", "bla", "blop", "ha", "ho", "he"));
        bindingSource1.Add(new Test("bli", "bla", "blop", "ha", "ho", "he"));

        // Initialize the DataGridView.
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

        // Initialize and add a text box column.
        DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.DataPropertyName = "Name1";
        column.Name = "Name1";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);

        // Initialize and add a check box column.
        column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.DataPropertyName = "Name2";
        column.Name = "Name2";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.DataPropertyName = "Name3";
        column.Name = "Name3";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.DataPropertyName = "Name4";
        column.Name = "Name4";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.DataPropertyName = "Name5";
        column.Name = "Name5";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.DataPropertyName = "Name6";
        column.Name = "Name6";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);

        // Initialize the form.
        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.Text = "DataGridView object binding demo";
    }

    #region "test object"
    private class Test
    {
        private string test1;
        private string test2;
        private string test3;
        private string test4;
        private string test5;
        private string test6;

        public Test(string s1, string s2, string s3, string s4, string s5, string s6)
        {
            test1 = s1;
            test2 = s2;
            test3 = s3;
            test4 = s4;
            test5 = s5;
            test6 = s6;
        }

        public Test()
        {
            test1 = "bla";
            test2 = "bla";
            test3 = "bla";
            test4 = "bla";
            test5 = "bla";
            test6 = "bla";
        }


        public string Test1
        {
            get
            {
                return test1;
            }
            set
            {
                test1 = value;
            }
        }

        public string Test2
        {
            get
            {
                return test2;
            }
            set
            {
                test2 = value;
            }
        }

        public string Test3
        {
            get
            {
                return test3;
            }
            set
            {
                test3 = value;
            }
        }

        public string Test4
        {
            get
            {
                return test4;
            }
            set
            {
                test4 = value;
            }
        }

        public string Test5
        {
            get
            {
                return test5;
            }
            set
            {
                test5 = value;
            }
        }

        public string Test6
        {
            get
            {
                return test6;
            }
            set
            {
                test6 = value;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new Form3());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Florian, after this line `dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;` check to see if `dataGridView1.DataBind()` method is available..

Answer (score 2):

You are binding columns to properties called `Name` from 1 to 6 but in your object there is no such properties. Change `Name` to `Test`. Ie

from this:

```
column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
column.DataPropertyName = "Name6";
column.Name = "Name6";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
```

to this:

```
column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
column.DataPropertyName = "Test6";
column.Name = "Name6";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
```

also as suggested by @noobob move your

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

to the end of method

Comment: Changing
column.DataPropertyName = "NameX";

to

column.DataPropertyName = "TestX";

solved the prob.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"DataPropertyName" property of every column must match the name of a property of the data object being evaluated. So if you just make one tiny change like this:

```
column.DataPropertyName = "Test1";
```

everything should work.

Comment: Changing column.DataPropertyName = "NameX"; to column.DataPropertyName = "TestX"; solved the prob.

Answer (score 0):

The `column.DataPropertyName` should be set to the property names you specified in the datasource class. Try This :

```
    column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column.DataPropertyName = "Test1";
    column.Name = "Test1";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);

    column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column.DataPropertyName = "Test2";
    column.Name = "Test2";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);

    column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column.DataPropertyName = "Test3";
    column.Name = "Test3";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
```

Comment: Changing column.DataPropertyName = "NameX"; to column.DataPropertyName = "TestX"; solved the prob.

Comment: @FlorianHeld I'm glad it helped. You could mark any of the answers given as accepted and/or Upvote them.